# Matlab SURF points to pixel coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matching, surf, matlab-cvst

I want to extract (x,y) pixel coordinates out of the SURF points returned, as an example in [the example provided here using Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.geometrictransformestimator-class.html). It is clear that using 'ptsIn(1).Location' I can return the (x,y) coordinates of the point. But the points retuned included some decimal points as well, as an example (102.9268, 51.7285). Is there any way to convert this to pixel positions in the image plane, or just averaging these values will give the pixel positions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand it further I tried the following code [in this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/surfpoints.plot.html).

```
% Extract SURF features
  I = imread('cameraman.tif');
  points = detectSURFFeatures(I);
  [features, valid_points] = extractFeatures(I, points);

% Visualize 10 strongest SURF features, including their 
% scales and orientation which were determined during the 
% descriptor extraction process.
  imshow(I); hold on;
  strongestPoints = valid_points.selectStrongest(10);
  strongestPoints.plot('showOrientation',true);
```

Then, tried the command `strongestPoints.Location` in the Matlab console, which returned the following (x,y) coordinates.

139.7482   95.9542
107.4502  232.0347
116.6112  138.2446
105.5152  172.1816
113.6975   48.7220
104.4210   75.7348
111.3914  154.4597
106.2879  175.2709
131.1298   98.3900
124.2933   64.4942

Since there is a coordinate (107.4502  232.0347), I tried to mark the row 232 as black (`I(232,:)=0;`) to see whether it matches 232.0347 y coordinate in the SURF point, and received the following figure. So it seems rounded values of the SURF points give the (x,y) pixel coordinates of the image.
[image]

Comment: This is correct. `detectSURFFeatures` detects the interest points with sub-pixel accuracy. So if you can get the x,y coordinates of the corresponding pixels by doing `round(points.Location)`.