# Get coordinates of inlier points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates, pixel, matlab-cvst

I need to find pixel values of inlier points obtained in object detection using `impixel()`. I am using the same code as provided in the example at the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html)

How can I get x,y coordinates of the inlier points being with respect to image dimensions.(Top-left corner of image considered as `0` row, `0` col) so that I can use the coordinates to find their respective pixel values. I couldn't find any solution in Matlab same as KeyPoint object in `C++` that gives coordinate values easily.

Comment: what input  image? what is inlier point?  (big difference in some  feature or matched such point with other image?) if you already have the coordinates in what coordinate system they are (if not in the image coordinates already)?

Comment: Both training and query images are 24bit RGB images.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421094/matlab-surf-points-to-pixel-coordinates?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `impixel` here. `impixel` lets you get the pixel value from in image displayed in a figure, which is not what you are trying to do.

In the example you are using, `inlierBoxPoints` and `inlierScenePoints` are SURFPoints objects. You can get the (x,y) locations of the points as `inlierBoxPoints.Location`.  Then you can get the pixel value for the i-th point as follows:

```
loc = round(inlierBoxPoints.Location(i, :));
pixVal = boxImage(loc(2), loc(1), :);
```

Keep in mind that in MATLAB the images are indexed as (row, col), and that the top-left corner pixel is (1,1), not (0,0). You have to round off the coordinates, because the points are detected with sub-pixel accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it. I get an error '"Subscript indices must be either real positive or logical". Here, does the "loc" contain coordinates as [x,y]. Also, as there are multiple inlier points, do I need to use a for loop.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain that you should round off the coordinates. If you want to avoid using a loop, you can use the `sub2ind` function to convert the row-column subscript into linear indices.